# Bubble Sort - If you need n operations to sort a list of size k, how many operations will you need approximately to sort a list of size 2k?

Tags: c, big-o

This is an optional question in a course I'm taking, and they provide the answer, 4n.  But now matter how much I think about it I cannot figure out how they came to this.  I'm still very new and just learning about big O notation so I'm sure I'm missing something simple but it doesn't make sense to me.  The way I think about it is bubble sort requires n * k operations, so if you make k into 2k I have n * 2k.  And I believe in worst-case scenario k = n - 1 so it's practically n * 2n AKA 3n.  I'm probably doing this completely wrong, but that's why I'm here for help.  My course didn't really (or I don't feel) it covered a problem like this so I'm just not sure how to approach it.  Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934636/bubble-sort-worst-case-example-is-onn-how

Comment: Simple, `size k` list requires `k^2` order of operations by Big-O. `size 2k` list requires `(2k)^2 = 4k^2` operations. Now, If `n ≈ k^2 => 4k^2 ≈ 4n`

Comment: Why does it require k^2?  I thought it was k * 2 not k squared?  Where did you get that?  If I can figure out where you got the squaring it would make a lot more sense to me.  Your answer is pushing me in the right direction but I'm still a little lost - sorry if I'm slow and thanks for your time.

EDIT: And why do parenthesis go around (2k), where is that determined?  Because that obviously changes the result as well.

Comment: bubble sort is a k^2 big O complexity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bubble sort is Big O k^2 complexity, both worst case and average

so we have n operations for size k, which implies that k^2 = n

so we double k, we have (2k)^2 = X or 4k^2 = X   where X =# of operations for 2k size

plug in the fact that n=k^2, and you have 4n=X

Theres your answer :)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  The only question I have left is when it goes from k^2 to (2k)^2 what dictates that we put the parenthesis there so that I'll know how to utilize this in the future?

Comment: the size. So Big O notation works based on the size of the input. So given size X, initially you have X=k. Later you have X=2k. So think of it as Big O x^2, and you are replacing the value of X. Order of operations tells us to do exponents before multiplication (PEMDAS!), so we make sure that we have a 'P' (parenthesis) that executes before the 'E' (exponent) to maintain the original formula