# How to get the worst case for bubble sort?

Tags: javascript

In the worst case using bubble sort, will do n - 1 steps, so what is that worst case, how i can know the worst case given an array in a function in Javascript?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Rabbits_and_turtles

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934636/bubble-sort-worst-case-example-is-onn-how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bubble sort worst case example is O(n\*n), how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934636/bubble-sort-worst-case-example-is-onn-how)

Answer (score 4):

If the array is sorted in reverse order, it will be the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

In general, any array in which the smallest element is at the last index will be a worst-case for bubble sort. A reverse sorted array is just one such case in which the smallest element is at the last index.

Comment: The answer is correct and generalized. Any array in which the smallest element is at the last index will be a worst-case for bubble sort. Reverse sorted array in one such case of my generalized answer.

Comment: I tested this suggestion and it's not true.

bubbleSort([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]); - sorted 36 times

bubbleSort([9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]); - sorted 15 times